Use Array in SAS proc freq?
I am doing an exploratory analysis to see if any variables are associated with someone "switching" from one type of treatment to another. I am running fisher's exact tests (because of a small sample size) to test associations before coming back to my team with any recommendations on how to proceed with the analysis.
The issue I am running into is that there are 22 variables that need to be compared to the "switch" variable and while I could hardcode every combination, it would be concise and cleaner if I could use an array or do loop to code these 22 tests in just a few lines.
I was able to successfully create an array with the variables I need.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!! I had tried to code the following
proc freq data=dataset;
tables switch_var*comp_vars(22)/fisher;
run;

When I did it returned with the following error :
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_, _CHAR_, _NUMERIC_. ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Arrays are only valid in data steps and some procedures (but not PROC FREQ).
Shortcut lists are more appropriate here most likely, if you have a naming convention or if the variables are side by side.
Examples:
proc freq data=dataset;
tables switch_var*(comp_vars1-comp_vars22)/fisher;
tables switch_var*(comp_vars:)/fisher;
tables switch_var*(measurement1--end_variable22)/fisher;
run;

Various ways to list variables are listed in this blog post:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html
